# Are there literary attestations of werewolves in the Classical period?

Tags: mythology, reference-request

The modern idea of werewolves seems to have arisen somewhere in the Middle Ages, after the spread of Christianity. But I vaguely remember a story in the *Satyricon* (specifically at Trimalchio's dinner) about a man turning into a wolf at the full moon.

Are there other stories of people transforming into wolves from Classical or pre-Classical times? (And back again: while Ovid writes about a lot of transformations, they're generally permanent.)

Comment: The story appears in sections 61–62 of the Satyricon

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6864/469 Does the mention in Naturalis Historia fit your requirements?

Comment: Related Mythology SE question: [The Origin of Werewolf: Deities Cursing People into Animals?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2174/the-origin-of-werewolf-deities-cursing-people-into-animals)

Comment: I would be very surprised, given the significance of the wolves in the common IE mythology, if the motif of the werewolf did not originate in the PIE times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example I remember, [Verg., Ecl., 8](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?q=Verg.%20Ecl.%208), 96

> Has herbas atque haec Ponto mihi lecta venena
>   ipse dedit Moeris; nascuntur plurima Ponto.
>   His ego saepe lupum fieri et se condere silvis
>   Moerim [...]

Lit. *Moeris himself gave me these herbs and choice Pontian potions (they are abundantly growing in Pontus). I saw myself not once how Moeris turned himself with them into a wolf and ran into the woods...*

---

Here is another (late 4th c.) mention, not known, AFAIK, from other sources, of Apollo Lyceus living with Cyrene in the shape of a wolf, assuming gods (and 4th c. sources) also qualify ([Serv. Hon., A., 4.377](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?q=Serv.+A.+4.377)):

> Apollinem Lyceum appellari dicunt sive de Lyco, quem vicit, et in victoriae suae testimonium hoc nomen induit [...] sive quod transfiguratus in lupum cum Cyrene concubuit: sive quod in lupi habitu Telchinas occiderit...