# How do you describe someone as a shapeshifter in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

Greco-Roman mythology is full of many examples of shape-changing. If you look only at Zeus/Jupiter alone, there are countless examples of him changing himself or changing others. Did the Romans have a specific word in Latin that meant "one-who-changes-shapes" like we do with "shapeshifter", or did they express this in other ways?

While I've found examples describing the act, I couldn't find anything used to describe a person or god as a shapeshifter.

Answer (score 18):

The word you want is *versipellis*.

In a story told by one of the guests at Trimalchio's dinner party in Petronius (*Satyricon* 62), it's used specifically to describe a werewolf, but it generally means 'One who can metamorphose himself into different shapes or forms' (OLD). It's also used of Jupiter in Plautus (*Amphitryon* 123).

Comment: This is much better than my suggestion!

Comment: I actually like having both answers! With both I could say something _Iulius multiformis versipellis est / Many-shaped Julius is a shapeshifter._

Comment: This word is also discussed in the following question: [What does a versipellis turn into?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7446)

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is [***multiformis***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Multiformis&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
While the dictionary entry doesn't seem have anything like a shapeshifter, this word would be well understood in proper context, with clear and familiar components.

I am not familiar with the Romans having a specific term like modern English does, so adapting other vocabulary for that purpose may well be the only route available.

Answer (score 3):

*Versipellis* is a good suggestion, but another, attested one is **pluriformis**:

> plūrĭformis , e, adj. plures-forma,
> I.having many forms, manifold, varied (postclass.): “pluriformi modo,” App. Flor. p. 341, 14; Mart. Cap. 7, § 729.